# Java fx - how to get the click mouse event from a chart pie

Tags: javafx, actionlistener, pie-chart

I am currently working on Java fx with pie chart and java fx scene Builder 1.1.

My question is the following :

HOW get the mouse click event from my pie chart?

Here is my code :

screen.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
```

-->

```
ScreenController

package screensframework;

import java.awt.Button;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

/**
* FXML Controller class
*
* @author Kenny
*/
public class Screen2Controller implements Initializable , ControlledScreen {

ScreensController myController;
/**
* Initializes the controller class.
*/
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}

public void setScreenParent(ScreensController screenParent){
    myController = screenParent;
}

@FXML
private void goToScreen1(ActionEvent event){
   myController.setScreen(ScreensFramework.screen1ID);
}

@FXML
private void goToScreen3(ActionEvent event){
   myController.setScreen(ScreensFramework.screen3ID);
}

/*________________________________________________________________________*/

@FXML
private GridPane gridPane;

@FXML
private Text detailsTitle;

@FXML
private ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData;

@FXML
private PieChart piechart = new PieChart(pieChartData);

@FXML 
private AnchorPane content;

@FXML 
private Button button2;



@FXML
private void handleButton1Action(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("test");
        }

@FXML public void handleMouseClick(MouseEvent arg0) 
{
    myController.setScreen(ScreensFramework.screen3ID);

}

@FXML
private void handleButton2Action(ActionEvent event) {
    gridPane.setGridLinesVisible(true);
    ReadExcelFile r = new ReadExcelFile();
    File f = new File("C:\\Users\\k.vanmeenen\\Desktop\\ExportDefectsGraph.xlsx");
    float[][] tab = r.ReadExcelGrid(f);

    pieChartData =
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new PieChart.Data("Blocking", tab[0][0]),
                new PieChart.Data("Non Blocking, disturbing", tab[1][0]),
                new PieChart.Data("Partial Blocking", tab[2][0]),
                new PieChart.Data("Cosmetic", tab[3][0]));

   piechart.setTitle("Defects per severity >");
   piechart.setData(pieChartData);

    String cssChart = ScreensFramework.class.getResource("ChartPieCss.css").toExternalForm();
    piechart.getStylesheets().add(cssChart);

    detailsTitle.setText("E-Contracting");


    Text rankTitle1 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[0][1])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle1,1,1);
    Text rankTitle2 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[0][2])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle2,2,1);
    Text rankTitle3 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[0][3])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle3,3,1);
    Text rankTitle4 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[0][4])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle4,4,1);
    Text rankTitle5 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[0][5])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle5,5,1);
    Text rankTitle6 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[0][6])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle6,6,1);
    Text rankTitle7 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[0][7])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle7,7,1);
    Text rankTitle8 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[0][8])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle8,8,1);
    Text rankTitle9 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[0][9])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle9,9,1);
    Text rankTitle10 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[0][10])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle10,10,1);
    Text rankTitle11 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[0][0])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle11,11,1);

    Text rankTitle21 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[1][1])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle21,1,2);
    Text rankTitle22 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[1][2])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle22,2,2);
    Text rankTitle23 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[1][3])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle23,3,2);
    Text rankTitle24 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[1][4])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle24,4,2);
    Text rankTitle25 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[1][5])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle25,5,2);
    Text rankTitle26 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[1][6])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle26,6,2);
    Text rankTitle27 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[1][7])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle27,7,2);
    Text rankTitle28 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[1][8])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle28,8,2);
    Text rankTitle29 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[1][9])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle29,9,2);
    Text rankTitle30 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[1][10])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle30,10,2);
    Text rankTitle31 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[1][0])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle31,11,2);


    Text rankTitle32 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[2][1])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle32,1,3);
    Text rankTitle33 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[2][2])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle33,2,3);
    Text rankTitle34 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[2][3])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle34,3,3);
    Text rankTitle35 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[2][4])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle35,4,3);
    Text rankTitle36 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[2][5])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle36,5,3);
    Text rankTitle37 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[2][6])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle37,6,3);
    Text rankTitle38 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[2][7])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle38,7,3);
    Text rankTitle39 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[2][8])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle39,8,3);
    Text rankTitle40 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[2][9])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle40,9,3);
    Text rankTitle41 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[2][10])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle41,10,3);
    Text rankTitle42 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[2][0])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle42,11,3);

    Text rankTitle42b = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[3][1])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle42b,1,4);
    Text rankTitle43 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[3][2])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle43,2,4);
    Text rankTitle44 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[3][3])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle44,3,4);
    Text rankTitle45 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[3][4])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle45,4,4);
    Text rankTitle46 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[3][5])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle46,5,4);
    Text rankTitle47 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[3][6])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle47,6,4);
    Text rankTitle48 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[3][7])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle48,7,4);
    Text rankTitle49 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[3][8])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle49,8,4);
    Text rankTitle50 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[3][9])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle50,9,4);
    Text rankTitle51 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[3][10])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle51,10,4);
    Text rankTitle52 = new Text(Double.toString(Math.floor(tab[3][0])));
    gridPane.add(rankTitle52,11,4);
}



@FXML
private void handleButtonClearAction(ActionEvent event) {
    ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData =
            FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    piechart.setTitle("");
    piechart.setData(pieChartData);
```

}
}

'Till now, I can clicked on each part of the pie chart and go to another screen but what I would like is when I press one of the part of the pie chart it recognized which one I clicked.

Thank you
Kenny

Comment: is there anybodody? nobody?     :'(

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer.

Add a normal label and on mouse click action to the PieChart, then add the following code:

```
@FXML
private void mouseClick(MouseEvent mouseevent ) {

   for (final PieChart.Data data : piechart.getData()) {
data.getNode().addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED,
    new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
            label.setTranslateX(e.getSceneX());
            label.setTranslateY(e.getSceneY());
            label.setText(String.valueOf(data.getPieValue()) + "%");
         }
    });
}



            }
```